# When spending a fraction of the coins in an address, can I send the remainder back to the same address?

Tags: protocol

Lets say an address has 150 unspent BTC, and I want to transfer 50 BTC to someone else, can I send the remainder (100 BTC) back to the original address? Is this impossible, a bad idea or something that isn't done very often for some other reason?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Can a Bitcoin transaction have the same address for input and output?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12746/5406)

Comment: @Murch, definitely a duplicate, but for some reason this question has produced a better answer.